# Resource about strategy in makruk?

Tags: makruk

[Makruk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makruk) is a Thai board game related to chess. According to former world chess champion [Vladimir Kramnik](http://www.chessvariants.com/oriental.dir/thaikramnik.html), who developed an interest in the game,

> Makruk Thai is more strategic than International Chess. You have to plan your operations with total care since Makruk Thai can be compared to an anticipated endgame of International Chess.

Since the game is so strategic, are there are books or other resources that teach some aspects of strategy in makruk? They need not be in English; German and French also work for me.

Answer (score 1):

The only detailed (non-Thai) resource on Makruk I could find so far is the book **"Thai Chess & Cambodian Chess (Makruk & Ouk Chatrang)" by Gary Gifford**. Besides the rules of both games including a dedicated chapter on counting rules with some endgame problems, the largest part of the thin book (<100 pages) is about openings and annotated games.

I think it is a good book to get started with Makruk, since it gives some basic idea of the strategy, but given the limited scope you can of course not expect deep analyses.

One side note: The author claims in several places that it is not possible to checkmate with 3 queens/met even if they cover both colors. This is not the case, and in one case where he even gives a specific position, [Stockfish](https://github.com/ianfab/Makruk-Stockfish) in fact finds a mate in 20 (where the counting rules would allow up to 59 moves).